# Single view with many models

Tags: django

I'm building an app to help me learn Django...basically, it's just a list of various media I own (CDs, DVDs, Books, Devices, Etc). It's entirely useless of course, but I'm trying to hit on all the things I might find in a "real world" app.

What I would like to do is have a main list view that will select a few items from each category. Say 5 CDs, 5 books, etc, etc, and mash them all up in a single listing.

The first thing that comes to mind is to just query them all and pass them via a context:

{"books" : Book.objects.all(), "DVDs": DVD.objects.all(), #etc etc etc, }

But I can't help but think that this is entirely inefficient. Is there a better/faster way that won't hit the DB so hard? Perhaps a fancy way of creating a "super" model that will poll other models and generate a list? Or something?

Or will Django cache this request anyway...so it won't hit the DB every time the page is requested?

What about using inheritance?

```
class Item(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    date_added = models.blahblahblah 

    class Meta: 
        abstract = True 

class DVD(Item): 
    run_time = models.IntegerField() 
    director = models.blahblah 

class Book(Item): 
    publisher = etc 
    author = etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create something like a *Product* model that can group CDs, DVDs, Books, etc., and represent that using generic relations:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    item = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class DVD(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    length = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('people.Person')
```

Then, like in Django's documentation, you can create products from existing DVDs or Books:

```
>>> adventure_time = DVD.objects.get(title='Adventure Time')
>>> adventure_time_product = Product(item=adventure_time, sku='123')
>>> adventure_time_product.save()
```

And then, in a view, you'll be able to just pass a queryset of products: `{'products': Product.objects.all()}`, and reference *item* to obtain each object in your template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.item }}  {# can be DVD or Book #}
{% endfor %}
```

Keep in mind that, while elegant, this isn't the most effective way (it won't have bad performance at all either), Django may query the database to obtain the *item* object. I'm not sure if using `select_related` can help.

Regarding caching, Django won't cache the request automatically, you need to setup caching yourself, but [it's very easy to do](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/cache/#setting-up-the-cache) :-)

Once you've got the cache setup, you just need to use [the `cache_page` decorator on your view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache).

You could instead [cache only the fragment in the template where the items are listed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching), I think that'd be most efficient.

Comment: **You could create something like a Product or Item model with a type field that can be CDs, DVDs, Books, etc.** Wouldn't it be better to have separate models though? A DVD does not have an artist or a song list, a CD does not have a page count, etc etc. It seems that they are different enough to warrant their own Models?

Comment: Like I said, it depends on your design. If it makes more sense to have separate models, you can still have a _Product_ or _Item_ model that relates to DVD, CD, and Book models by using [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1).

Comment: Eureka! This is what I need....if I am understanding correctly.

Basically I would have objects (Models, such as DVD, Book, etc). Each of these models would have fields unique to that type of "thing". A DVD object would have a run_time attribute, a director attribute, etc, and a Book would have a publisher attribute, a page_num attribute, etc. THEN, I would lump all of these items (books and DVDs and whatever) into a single Items Model. Really all I would need in Items would be a name attribute...

Am I getting the jist of this? This is all pretty new to me, so...

Comment: Is there any way I could trouble you for a very simple example of this, by the way? The docs are nice, but somewhat cryptic for me.

Comment: again, depends on what you're building and how you design it, if you want to ask about inheritance please post a new question :-)

Comment: THANK YOU!!! So I think I am almost understanding this. However...I just stumbled upon inheritance for models. Wouldn't that be better and far simpler? I could just have a base "Item" class, then each type of thing could inherit from it.
'
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.blahblahblah
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class DVD(Item):
    run_time = models.IntegerField()
    director = models.blahblah

class Book(Item):
    publisher = etc
    author = etc
'